# Set the year that is assumed when parsing partial date values in .NET

Tags: c#, parsing, date

I need to parse a date string which could be in any reasonable format. For example:

- `2012-12-25`
- `25 december 2012`
- `25 dec`
- `17:35`

Some of these strings contain ambiguous dates which can result in several possible `DateTime` values (E.g. `25 dec` can be interpreted as `2012-12-25`, `2011-12-25`, `1066-12-25`, etc).

The way `DateTime.Parse` currently handles these ambiguous values is by using the current system date to determine the context. So if the current date is **26th July 2012** the string `25 dec` is assumed to be in the current year and is parsed as `2012-12-25`

Is it somehow possible to change this behaviour and set the current date context myself?

Comment: this is close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003088/using-datetime-tryparseexact-without-knowing-the-year

Comment: more good info here too; not quite a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024273/convert-a-two-digit-year-to-a-four-digit-year

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is post processing the date.  You have the string afterwards and you have the year in the DateTime object.  If the string does not contain the year then set the year yourself.

```
if(! string.contains(DateTime.Year.toString() ) {
    // Set the year yourself
}
```

Comment: What if the string is "25 dec 12'? Then the year will be set to 2012, but the string does not contain "2012".

Comment: `DateTime.Year` returns the current year as 4 digits, so this will fail for any input date with a 2 digit year. Checking just two digits will be ambiguous with months/dates in some cases.

Comment: That's not a bad workaround. My concern is that the current year might legitimately exist elsewhere in the date string. E.g. "2008-11-01T19:35:00.2012000Z"

Comment: True, I guess it would depend on how varied the inputs really are.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect to get "incomplete" date/time information in various formats, you could try parsing the text as specific different formats least-detailed to most-detailed.  For example:

```
var text = "June 15";
DateTime datetime;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "m", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out datetime))
{
    // was just month, day, replace year with specific value:
    datetime = new DateTime(1966, datetime.Month, datetime.Day);
}
else
{
    // wasn't just month, day, try parsing a "whole" date/time:
    datetime = DateTime.Parse(text);
}
```

...this code tries to parse month/day format in the current culture (if you have a specific one, independent of current culture, you can replace "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture" with a culture that has the format you want).  If that fails, it assumes the text is more detailed and goes on to parse it as you normally would.

If your date/times are not local, don't use `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal`.  I always recommend that date/time data that is stored in any way (like serialized to text) that you always use Universal; because you don't know what culture was in play when the data was serialized.  Universal is the only reliable way to get date/time data on level playing field.  In which case use `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUnivesal`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to deal with `IFormatProvider` stuff but that may take a while. As a quick solution I can propose an extension method:

```
public static class MyDateTimeStringExtensions
{
    public static DateTime ToDateTimeWithYear(this string source, int year)
    {
        var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(source);

        return dateTime.AddYears(year - dateTime.Year);
    }
}
 ....
"2/2".ToDateTimeWithYear(2001) // returns 2/2/2001 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem.  DateTime.Parse or DateTime.TryParse will assume the time of day is 00:00:00 when the string contains no time of day information.  Just as with the year assumption, there is no way to specify a different time of day to use as the default.  This is a real problem, because the time to set these defaults is *before* the parsing method goes through all its detailed steps.  Otherwise, you have to very painfully reinvent the wheel to determine whether the string contained information that would override the default.

I looked at the source code of DateTime.TryParse, and as to be expected, Microsoft have gone out of their way to make it hard to extend the DateTime class.  So I've cooked up some code that uses reflection to leverage what it can from the source code of DateTime.  This has some significant drawbacks:

- The reflection-using code is awkward
- The reflection-using code calls internal members which might change if the .Net framework is upgraded
- The reflection-using code will run slower than some hypothetical alternative that didn't need to use reflection

In my case, I judged that nothing could be more awkward than having to reinvent DateTime.TryParse from scratch.  I have unit tests that will indicate if the internal members have changed.  And I believe the performance penalty is insignificant in my case.

My code is below.  This code is used to override the default hour/minute/second, but I think it could be easily modified or expanded to override the default year or something else.  The code is faithfully imitating the internal code of one of the overloads of the internal System.DateTimeParse.TryParse (it does the real work of DateTime.TryParse), although I had to use awkward reflection to do so.  The only thing effectively different from System.DateTimeParse.TryParse is that it assigns a default hour/minute/second instead of leaving them all at zero.

For reference, this is the method of class DateTimeParse that I am imitating

```
        internal static bool TryParse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles, out DateTime result) { 
        result = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTimeResult resultData = new DateTimeResult();  // The buffer to store the parsing result.
        resultData.Init();
        if (TryParse(s, dtfi, styles, ref resultData)) { 
            result = resultData.parsedDate;
            return true; 
        } 
        return false;
    }
```

And here is my code

```
public static class TimeExtensions
{
    private static Assembly _sysAssembly;
    private static Type _dateTimeParseType, _dateTimeResultType;
    private static MethodInfo _tryParseMethod, _dateTimeResultInitMethod;
    private static FieldInfo _dateTimeResultParsedDateField,
                _dateTimeResultHourField, _dateTimeResultMinuteField, _dateTimeResultSecondField;
    /// <summary>
    /// This private method initializes the private fields that store reflection information
    /// that is used in this class.  The method is designed so that it only needs to be called
    /// one time.
    /// </summary>
    private static void InitializeReflection()
    {
        // Get a reference to the Assembly containing the 'System' namespace
        _sysAssembly = typeof(DateTime).Assembly;
        // Get non-public types of 'System' namespace
        _dateTimeParseType = _sysAssembly.GetType("System.DateTimeParse");
        _dateTimeResultType = _sysAssembly.GetType("System.DateTimeResult");
        // Array of types for matching the proper overload of method System.DateTimeParse.TryParse
        Type[] argTypes = new Type[] 
        {
            typeof(String), 
            typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo), 
            typeof(DateTimeStyles), 
            _dateTimeResultType.MakeByRefType()
        };
        _tryParseMethod = _dateTimeParseType.GetMethod("TryParse",
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, argTypes, null);
        _dateTimeResultInitMethod = _dateTimeResultType.GetMethod("Init",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        _dateTimeResultParsedDateField = _dateTimeResultType.GetField("parsedDate",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        _dateTimeResultHourField = _dateTimeResultType.GetField("Hour",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        _dateTimeResultMinuteField = _dateTimeResultType.GetField("Minute",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        _dateTimeResultSecondField = _dateTimeResultType.GetField("Second",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    } 
    /// <summary>
    /// This method converts the given string representation of a date and time to its DateTime
    /// equivalent and returns true if the conversion succeeded or false if no conversion could be
    /// done.  The method is a close imitation of the System.DateTime.TryParse method, with the
    /// exception that this method takes a parameter that allows the caller to specify what the time
    /// value should be when the given string contains no time-of-day information.  In contrast,
    /// the method System.DateTime.TryParse will always apply a value of midnight (beginning of day)
    /// when the given string contains no time-of-day information.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">the string that is to be converted to a DateTime</param>
    /// <param name="result">the DateTime equivalent of the given string</param>
    /// <param name="defaultTime">a DateTime object whose Hour, Minute, and Second values are used
    /// as the default in the 'result' parameter.  If the 's' parameter contains time-of-day 
    /// information, then it overrides the value of 'defaultTime'</param>
    public static Boolean TryParse(String s, out DateTime result, DateTime defaultTime)
    {
        // Value of the result if no conversion can be done
        result = DateTime.MinValue;
        // Create the buffer that stores the parsed result
        if (_sysAssembly == null) InitializeReflection();
        dynamic resultData = Activator.CreateInstance(_dateTimeResultType);
        _dateTimeResultInitMethod.Invoke(resultData, new Object[] { });
        // Override the default time values of the buffer, using this method's parameter
        _dateTimeResultHourField.SetValue(resultData, defaultTime.Hour);
        _dateTimeResultMinuteField.SetValue(resultData, defaultTime.Minute);
        _dateTimeResultSecondField.SetValue(resultData, defaultTime.Second);
        // Create array parameters that can be passed (using reflection) to 
        // the non-public method DateTimeParse.TryParse, which does the real work
        Object[] tryParseParams = new Object[]
        {
            s, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, resultData
        };
        // Call non-public method DateTimeParse.TryParse
        Boolean success = (Boolean)_tryParseMethod.Invoke(null, tryParseParams);
        if (success)
        {
            // Because the DateTimeResult object was passed as a 'ref' parameter, we need to
            // pull its new value out of the array of method parameters
            result = _dateTimeResultParsedDateField.GetValue((dynamic)tryParseParams[3]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

--**EDIT**--
I subsequently realized that I need to do the same thing for method DateTime.TryParseExact.  However, the above approach did not work for TryParseExact, which leads me to worry that the approach is even more fragile than I thought.  Oh well.  Happily, I was able to think of a very different approach for TryParseExact which does not use any reflection

```
        public static Boolean TryParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider,
                            DateTimeStyles style, out DateTime result, DateTime defaultTime)
    {
        // Determine whether the format requires that the time-of-day is in the string to be converted.
        // We do this by creating two strings from the format, which have the same date but different
        // time of day.  If the two strings are equal, then clearly the format contains no time-of-day
        // information.
        Boolean willApplyDefaultTime = false;
        DateTime testDate1 = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 2, 15, 15);
        DateTime testDate2 = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 17, 47, 29);
        String testString1 = testDate1.ToString(format);
        String testString2 = testDate2.ToString(format);
        if (testString1 == testString2)
            willApplyDefaultTime = true;

        // Let method DateTime.TryParseExact do all the hard work
        Boolean success = DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, provider, style, out result);

        if (success && willApplyDefaultTime)
        {
            DateTime rawResult = result;
            // If the format contains no time-of-day information, then apply the default from
            // this method's parameter value.
            result = new DateTime(rawResult.Year, rawResult.Month, rawResult.Day,
                             defaultTime.Hour, defaultTime.Minute, defaultTime.Second);
        }
        return success;
    }
```